# route (react-navigation) type in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

For navigations, I am using `useNavigation from '@react-navigation/native';`

I am using this to pass data between two screens in my app:

```
type UserDetailsProps = {
  onDeleteContact: (id: number) => void;
  route: any;
};
```

I don't want to use the `any` time but I don't know what other type is suitable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this type:

```
type RouteParams = {
  firstName?: string;
}

route?: RouteProp<Record<string, RouteParams>, ''>;
```

Notice that RouteProp is a named export of `@react-navigation/native`

Comment: I was using values like this: ```firstName={route.params.firstName}``` if I change the ```any``` with how you described, I start getting errors ike ```Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)```

Comment: updated my answer accordingly, changing the `object | undefined` type to a custom one should fix this